# How to make a customize object copy? Java

Tags: java

How can I make a copy of `listObject` ?

class of **listObject**:

```
static class listObject {
        ArrayList<String> diseases;
        ArrayList<String> images;

        static class guide {
            ArrayList<String> guideTitle;
            ArrayList<String> guideText;
            ArrayList<String> guideImage;
        }
    }
```

Here is my **copy** function:

```
public static Object copy(Object orig) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // Write the object out to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(orig);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Make an input stream from the byte array and read
            // a copy of the object back in.
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
            obj = in.readObject();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

When I call the copy() function **it's return null:**

```
listObject list;
listObject _tempList = new listObject();
list = (listObject) copy( (Object) _tempList);
```

Comment: The only place `obj` could be set to a non-null value is by `in.readObject`, so it looks like that method is returning null.

Comment: Does your listObject class implement the `serializable` or `externalizable` interface?  Only those classes can be read from streams.

Comment: what is `salud` above?

Comment: The name of the super class, let me clear it in the code.

Comment: @DavidChoweller it doesn't

Comment: If it doesn't implement serializable, that explains your error.

Comment: Yes, it was that the error. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listObject should implement Serializable. Change listObject as below.

```
class listObject implements Serializable{
ArrayList<String> diseases;
ArrayList<String> images;

static class guide {
    ArrayList<String> guideTitle;
    ArrayList<String> guideText;
    ArrayList<String> guideImage;
}
}
```